# Cerrar acción al pulsar una tecla (ESC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

tengo esta función, la que se supone que hace que abra un input y cuando esta abierto con el ESC se cierre, funciona la cuestión es que cuando el input esta cerrado al presionar ESC se abre de igual manera, no estaria logrando bloquear la acción al tener el input cerrado

```
<div class="iconB" id="iconB"></div>

<div class="searchh" id="searchh" >
          <div class="inputFB">
           <input class="inputB" type="text" name="termino" id="termino" placeholder="Producto que desea buscar..." aria-label="Search">
          </div>
       </div>
               
               <script>
                   
                   
                     $(document).ready(function(){
                           Act1(); 
                           Act2(); 

                      });
                   
                        function Act1(){
                            $('#iconB').on('click', function(event) {
                                $('#iconB').toggleClass('activa');
                                $('#searchh').toggleClass('activo');
                                $('#bgg').toggleClass('bggA');
                                $('#fix').toggleClass('fix');
                                $('#termino').toggle('show');
                                $('#TablaB').toggle('show');
                                $('#termino').val('');
                            });
                        };
                   
                            $(document).keyup(function(e){
                                if(e.which==27) {
                                    $('#iconB').click();
                                }
                       })
                        
                        function Act2(){
                            $('#clear').on('click', function(event) {
                                $('#iconB').toggleClass('activo');
                            });
                        };
                        
                   
                   </script>
```

Comment: Te basta con una función, controlando si está abierto o cerrado, y actuar de una forma y otra en consecuencia. Es sólo pensar un poco.

Comment: El punto no es que no lo piense, si no que no sabría bien como "tomar" si esta abierto o cerrado, estoy recién comenzando con esto, por eso la consulta

Comment: Te puede servir saber si el elemento tiene asignada o no determinada clase CSS, eso lo puedes hacer con hasClass(). https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: Por favor, utiliza las etiquetas que tengan que ver con tu duda... aquí no hay ni php ni java (imagino que querías decir javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta solucionado, dejo el código por si a alguien le llegara a necesitar algo parecido, simplemente le dijo que en vez de tomar el ID del botón tomara la class, la cual cambia al estar abierto y quedaría algo asi....

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
 if(e.which==27) {
$('.iconB.activa').click();
 }
 })
```

Como dije, simplemente tomo la Class en vez del ID, por lo cual al estar cerrado su clase seria .IconB y al darle click al "botón" pasaría a ser .iconB.activa, por ende la función solo se ejecuta cuando el "botón" tiene esa clase y no cuando esta cerrado